# Comma separated inputs instead of space separated inputs for argparse

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'm using `argparse` to receive inputs from the command line to run my script.

My current input string looks like this:

```
path> python <\filename\\> -t T1 T2 T3 -f F1 F2
```

Is there a parameter in argparse such that instead of separating inputs by space, I can separate them by commas?

In other words:

```
path> python <\filename\\> -t T1,T2,T3 -f F1,F2
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no such feature in `argparse`.

Alternatives:

- post-process the `args` namespace and split/parse the values manually
- define a custom `action` and split/parse the values manually
- define a custom `type` and split/parse the values manually
- subclass `ArgumentParser` and customise [`ArgumentParser.convert_arg_line_to_args`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.convert_arg_line_to_args)

Comment: Thanks for the info.   It's sad that the author or argparse made the horrible decision to not use commas as delimiters.   It makes code ugly.

Answer (score 5):

There are some useful answers here already, but I wanted a bit more: splitting on commas, validating values with `choices`, and getting useful error messages, so below I offer a solution.

#### Simple Version

As a first pass, we can just pass in an appropriate function to the `type` parameter:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='cmd')
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', type=lambda arg: arg.split(','))
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'a,b,c'])
Namespace(foo=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

But this doesn't work with `choices` because it checks if the whole list is in choices and not each value:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='cmd')
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', type=lambda arg: arg.split(','), choices=('a', 'b', 'c'))
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'a,b,c'])
usage: cmd [-h] [--foo {a,b,c}]
cmd: error: argument --foo: invalid choice: ['a', 'b', 'c'] (choose from 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

Setting `nargs` to something like `*` or `+` checks each value, but only for space-separated arguments (e.g., `--foo a b`) and not the comma-separated ones. It seems like there is no supported way to check if each value is in the choices if we produce the list ourselves. Therefore we need to raise errors ourselves via the `type` parameter (as Shiplu Mokaddim [partially implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59267302/1441112)). Creating a custom [Action](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/argparse.html#argparse.Action) class sounds promising as actions have access to the choices, but the action happens *after* the `type` function applies and values are checked, so we still couldn't use the `choices` parameter on `add_argument()` for this purpose.

#### Better Version

Here is a solution using a custom `type` function. We this function to take a list of valid choices, but since the function for type conversion can only take an argument string, we need to wrap it in a class (and define the special `__call__()` method) or a function closure. This solution uses the latter.

```
>>> def csvtype(choices):
...     """Return a function that splits and checks comma-separated values."""
...     def splitarg(arg):
...         values = arg.split(',')
...         for value in values:
...             if value not in choices:
...                 raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(
...                     'invalid choice: {!r} (choose from {})'
...                     .format(value, ', '.join(map(repr, choices))))
...         return values
...     return splitarg
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='cmd')
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', type=csvtype(('a', 'b', 'c')))
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'a,b,c'])
Namespace(foo=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'a,b,d'])
usage: cmd [-h] [-f F]
cmd: error: argument -f: invalid choice: 'd' (choose from 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

Notice that we get an appropriate error as well. For this, be sure to use `argparse.ArgumentTypeError` and not `argparse.ArgumentError` inside the function.

#### Other Options

User wim [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48714541/1441112) some other options not discussed above. I don't find those attractive for the following reasons:

- Post-processing the argument after parsing means you have to do more work to get the error messages to be consistent with those from `argparse`. Just raising `argparse.ArgumentError` will lead to a stacktrace. Also, `argparse` catches errors raised during parsing and alters them to specify the option that was used, which you'd otherwise need to do manually.
- Subclassing `ArgumentParser` is more work, and `convert_arg_line_to_args()` is for reading arguments from a file, not the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd say the simple option is better than the better one :) it's more readable and concise, plus, it immediately makes it clear that the feature is not supported directly by the API.

Answer (score 2):

You can use module `shlex` to extract the parameters, then replace commas with spaces, and pass the results to `argparse` for further processing:

```
comma_args = shlex.split("-t T1,T2,T3 -f F1,F2")
# ['-t', 'T1,T2,T3', '-f', 'F1,F2']
args = [x.replace(","," ") for x in comma_args]
# ['-t', 'T1 T2 T3', '-f', 'F1 F2']
parse_args(args)
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure compatibility with choices, I use two parsers:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3    
import argparse    
    
def main():    
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()    
    parser.add_argument("--arg", type=str, metavar="ARG[,ARG,...]")
    
    # Pass the usage to the subparser, remove the usage: prefix.
    subparser_usage = parser.format_usage().replace("usage: ", "", 1)  
    subparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage=subparser_usage)                                    
    subparser.add_argument("arg", nargs="*", type=int, choices=[1, 2, 3])    
    
    args = parser.parse_args()    
    if args.arg:    
        subargs = subparser.parse_args(args.arg.split(","))    
        args.arg = subargs.arg    
        
    print(args)    
     
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main()
```

This fulfills all possible requirements:

- easy and understandable
- involves only argparse
- choices are ensured with a correct usage and help message
- this allows to have also positional arguments (thanks to the comma separated list)
- See the following examples:

```
$ ./example --arg 1,2,3
Namespace(arg=[1, 2, 3])
$ ./example --arg 1,2,4
usage: example [-h] [--arg ARG[,ARG,...]]
example: error: argument arg: invalid choice: 4 (choose from 1, 2, 3)
$ ./example --arg 1
Namespace(arg=[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here this *comma-separated input* is actually a different *type*. All you have to is to define the type.
Here I define a custom type that does it.

```
class DelimiterSeperatedInput:
  def __init__(self, item_type, separator=','):
    self.item_type = item_type
    self.separator = separator

  def __call__(self, value):
    values = []
    try:
      for val in value.split(self.separator):
         typed_value = self.item_type(val)
         values.append(typed_value)
    except Exception:
      raise ArgumentError("%s is not a valid argument" % value)
    return values

parser.add_argument('-t', type=DelimiterSeperatedInput(str),
                    help='comma separated string values')
parser.add_argument('-f', type=DelimiterSeperatedInput(float, ":"), 
                    help="colon separated floats')
```

This code may not work as-is, you might have to fix. But it was to give an idea.

**Note:** I could reduce the `__call__` function body by using `list`, `map` etc. But then it wouldn't be very readable. Once you get the idea, you can do kinds of stuff with it.

Answer (score -1):

If you're okay with space not comma separated, then it's builtin to [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

```
In [1]: from argparse import ArgumentParser

In [2]: parser = ArgumentParser()

In [3]: parser.add_argument('-a', nargs='+')
Out[3]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-a'], dest='a', nargs='+', const=None, 
                     default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

In [4]: parser.parse_args(['-a', 'foo', 'bar'])
Out[4]: Namespace(a=['foo', 'bar'])
```