# Allow argparse nargs="+" to accept comma-separated input with choices

Tags: python, argparse

I want to use argparse's {choices} parameter, but allow the user to input any number of items from choices. For example if choices is [1,2,3], I would like the following to be valid:

```
--arg 1
--arg 1,2
--arg 1,3
```

etc.

However it seems like choices doesn't accept a comma-separated input when using nargs="+". Is there any way around this? I still want to enforce that the passed in options are within the set of choices that I defined, to error-check for weird inputs.

Comment: Does the list have to be comma-separated? The standard `argparse` format would be space separated: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs

Comment: @Blorgbeard because of the limitation of argparse which won’t allow having both a flag with nargs and positional arguments. See [the issue itself](https://bugs.python.org/issue9338) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26985650/2622010)

Comment: @jj172 see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74144448/2622010). I could not answer your question as it is closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I agree - You would think that the API would allow someone to do that by now right?

Well anyways, the workaround I've always used was the following:

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Why doesn't argparse support list of args?")
parser.add_argument('--arg', type=str)
arg_list = parser.parse_args().args.split(",")
# if you wanted integers:
arg_list = [int(x) for x in arg_list]
```

AKA: Take in a string and process it yourself.

Comment: Hey sorry, I actually changed my question a bit. I want to enforce using "choices", which I didn't initially mention - any ideas on how to have that work?

Comment: Do you need to use choices? Why not just use a set and check the results afterwards?

Comment: I like the CLI that choices provides, offering the user feedback if they enter an incorrect option. Honestly I think I'm leaning towards just not using comma-separated inputs :P

Comment: That's fair. I think then you should take @toheedNiaz's answer :)

Comment: It's hard to believe that it doesn't accept commas as delimiters.   Yes, you can work around that, but it's ugly.

Answer (score 1):

This one-line code gives you all possible subsets of your choices.

```
    from itertools import combinations, chain
    allsubsets = lambda n: list(chain(*[combinations(range(n), ni) for ni in range(n+1)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import argparse, sys
print(sys.argv)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--arg', nargs='+', choices=[1,2,3], type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

some runs

```
1455:~/mypy$ python stack49824248.py --arg 1 
['stack49824248.py', '--arg', '1']
Namespace(arg=[1])

1455:~/mypy$ python stack49824248.py --arg 1 3 2 1
['stack49824248.py', '--arg', '1', '3', '2', '1']
Namespace(arg=[1, 3, 2, 1])

1456:~/mypy$ python stack49824248.py --arg 1,2
['stack49824248.py', '--arg', '1,2']
usage: stack49824248.py [-h] [--arg {1,2,3} [{1,2,3} ...]]
stack49824248.py: error: argument --arg: invalid int value: '1,2'
```

The shell, together with the interpreter, splits the input on spaces, and provides a list of strings in `sys.argv`.  That's what `parser` handles.

With `+`, the `--arg` action accepts a list of strings (to the end or next flag).  Each string is passed through the `type` function, and the result compared to the `choices` (if provided). In this case, `type` is `int`, so the choices can be integers as well.  Without the `type`, `choices` would have to be `['1','2','3']`.

If I change the argument to:

```
parser.add_argument('--arg', nargs='+', choices=['1','2','3','1,2','2,3'])
```

it will accept some strings with commas:

```
1456:~/mypy$ python stack49824248.py --arg 1
['stack49824248.py', '--arg', '1']
Namespace(arg=['1'])
1505:~/mypy$ python stack49824248.py --arg 1,2
['stack49824248.py', '--arg', '1,2']
Namespace(arg=['1,2'])
1505:~/mypy$ python stack49824248.py --arg 1,2,3
['stack49824248.py', '--arg', '1,2,3']
usage: stack49824248.py [-h] [--arg {1,2,3,1,2,2,3} [{1,2,3,1,2,2,3} ...]]
stack49824248.py: error: argument --arg: invalid choice: '1,2,3' (choose from '1', '2', '3', '1,2', '2,3')
```

I didn't include the '1,2,3' choice, so it rejected that.  Note also that I dropped the `int` `type`, since `int('1,2')` will fail.

So if you need to accept '1,2,3', do your own split and choices test after parsing (or possibly as a custom `Action` class).

```
In [16]: [(int(x) in [1,2,3]) for x in '1,2,3'.split(',')]
Out[16]: [True, True, True]
In [17]: [(int(x) in [1,2,3]) for x in '1,2,4'.split(',')]
Out[17]: [True, True, False]
In [18]: [(int(x) in [1,2,3]) for x in '1,a,4'.split(',')]
....
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```